# Strange behaviour with mapView in CreateForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i come today with issue related to react-native and namely the strange behaviour i encountered. So, the issue is sorely connected with Map. When I click to select on Map a place and set a marker it does it. But when i want to place the marker somewhere else and i do it. When I save the marker position etc. and come back, the previous image of the map is displayed and not the one with marker. Below I've sent the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  launchImageLibraryAsync,
  useMediaLibraryPermissions,
} from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import {
  Alert,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  Pressable,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import IonIcons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

const CreateForm = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);
  const [isEndOpened, setIsEndOpened] = useState(false);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [dateTitle, setDateTitle] = useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDateTitle, setEndDateTitle] = useState(null);
  const [finalImages, setFinalImages] = useState([]);
  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(null);
  const [markerCoords, setMarkerCoords] = useState(null);

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params && isFocused) {
      setCurrentLocation(route.params.mapLayout);
      setMarkerCoords(route.params.markerCoords);
    }
  }, [route, isFocused]);

  const getLocationPermission = async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
      return;
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
    console.log(location);

    const locationObject = {
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0034,
    };

    setCurrentLocation(locationObject);
  };

  const [status, requestPermission] = useMediaLibraryPermissions();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "New Travel story",
      headerRight: () => {},
    });
  }, []);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpened(true);
  };

  const endModalOpen = () => {
    setIsEndOpened(true);
  };

  const selectImages = async () => {
    if (status.granted) {
      const imageLibrary = await launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsMultipleSelection: true,
      });
      if (imageLibrary.assets === null) {
        setFinalImages([]);
        return;
      }

      const allImages = [...finalImages, ...imageLibrary.assets];

      if (allImages.length > 15) {
        Alert.alert(
          "Amount of pictures exceeded !",
          "You are able only to add 15 pictures, in order not letting the app to break up. If you'd like to change all Images, click the button and choose again."
        );
        setFinalImages((prev) => {
          const maxAmount = prev.slice(0, 15);
          return [...maxAmount];
        });

        return;
      }

      setFinalImages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, ...imageLibrary.assets];
      });
    } else {
      await requestPermission();
    }
  };

  const navigateToMapSelect = () => {
    navigation.navigate("MapSelect", {
      coords: currentLocation,
      marker: markerCoords ? markerCoords : null,
    });
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 16 }}>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: 24, fontWeight: "500" }}>
        Prepend a new Travel story{" "}
        <IonIcons name="airplane-sharp" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "300" }}>
        And save the memories forever{" "}
        <IonIcons name="infinite-sharp" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} />
      </Text>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <View>
          <Text>Place Name:</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "black",
              padding: 5,
              borderRadius: 5,
              color: "white",
            }}
            placeholder="Type the name of the travel-place"
            placeholderTextColor="gray"
          />
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>Description:</Text>
          <TextInput
            multiline
            placeholder="Type the description"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "black",
              padding: 5,
              borderRadius: 5,
              color: "white",
            }}
            placeholderTextColor="gray"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ gap: 6, padding: 5, justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <View>
            <Text>Travel start:{dateTitle}</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "black",
                borderRadius: 4,
                padding: 6,
              }}
              android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
              onPress={openModal}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Select time</Text>
            </Pressable>
            {isOpened && (
              <DateTimePicker
                value={date ? date : new Date()}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setDate(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
                  console.log(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
                  setDateTitle(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp).toUTCString());
                  setIsOpened(false);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text>Travel end:{endDateTitle}</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={{ backgroundColor: "black", borderRadius: 4, padding: 6 }}
              android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
              onPress={endModalOpen}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Select time</Text>
            </Pressable>
            {isEndOpened && (
              <DateTimePicker
                value={endDate ? endDate : new Date()}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setEndDate(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
                  console.log(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
                  setEndDateTitle(
                    new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp).toUTCString()
                  );
                  setIsEndOpened(false);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Pressable
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "black",
              borderRadius: 4,
              padding: 6,
              margin: 12,
            }}
            android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
            onPress={selectImages}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
              Select Images <MaterialCommunityIcons name="camera" />
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>

        {finalImages.length === 0 && (
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            You haven't picked any image yet 
          </Text>
        )}

        {finalImages.length > 0 && (
          <>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "600",
                textAlign: "center",
                verticalAlign: "middle",
                margin: 4,
              }}
            >
              You have picked already {finalImages.length} pictures 
            </Text>

            <View
              style={{
                gap: 6,
                flexWrap: "wrap",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              {finalImages.map((image, index) => (
                <Image
                  key={index}
                  source={{ uri: image.uri }}
                  style={{
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    objectFit: "cover",
                    margin: 5,
                  }}
                />
              ))}
            </View>
          </>
        )}

        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600", padding: 6, textAlign: "center" }}>
            Choose the place on map that you visited:
          </Text>
          <MapView
            scrollEnabled={false}
            zoomEnabled={false}
            initialRegion={currentLocation}
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 3,
            }}
          >
            {markerCoords && <Marker coordinate={markerCoords} />}
          </MapView>

          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
              gap: 6,
            }}
          >
            <Pressable
              onPress={getLocationPermission}
              android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
              style={{
                padding: 5,
                margin: 5,
                backgroundColor: "black",
                alignItems: "center",
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
                Share Your Location{" "}
                <IonIcons name="location" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
              </Text>
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable
              onPress={navigateToMapSelect}
              android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
              style={{
                padding: 5,
                margin: 5,
                backgroundColor: "black",
                alignItems: "center",
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
                Select on Map <IonIcons name="map" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>

        <Pressable
          style={{ backgroundColor: "black", padding: 6, borderRadius: 4 }}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log(route.params);
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>Submit</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default CreateForm;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Pressable, Text, View } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";

import IonIcons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";

const MapSelect = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [markerCoords, setMarkerCoords] = useState(null);
  const [newMapLayout, setNewMapLayout] = useState(null);
  const coordsForMap = route.params.coords;
  const existingMarkerCoords = route.params.marker;

  const selectPlaceOnMap = (e) => {
    const coords = e.nativeEvent.coordinate;

    const newMapsCoords = {
      latitude: coords.latitude,
      longitude: coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    };
    setNewMapLayout(newMapsCoords);
    setMarkerCoords(coords);

    console.log(newMapsCoords);
    console.log(coords);
  };

  const saveMarker = () => {
    navigation.navigate("StackScreen", {
      mapLayout: newMapLayout,
      markerCoords: markerCoords,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (existingMarkerCoords) {
      setMarkerCoords(existingMarkerCoords);
    }
  }, [existingMarkerCoords]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions(
      {
        headerRight: () => (
          <Pressable onPress={saveMarker}>
            <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
              Save <IonIcons name="save-sharp" />
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        ),
      },
      []
    );
  }, [saveMarker]); // Listen to changes in newMapLayout and markerCoords

  return (
    <View>
      <MapView
        initialRegion={coordsForMap}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        onPress={selectPlaceOnMap}
      >
        {markerCoords && <Marker coordinate={markerCoords} />}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MapSelect;
```

Well i did all my best, but actually my attempts didn't work. So I expect that after I save the marker, the MapView will display the place with the marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT, THE ONLY THING NEEDED WAS TO SET region. I reckon I won't be sober this night !

BEYOND INITIALREGION ADD region !

```
 <View>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600", padding: 6, textAlign: "center" }}>
        Choose the place on map that you visited:
      </Text>
      <MapView
        scrollEnabled={false}
        zoomEnabled={false}
        initialRegion={initalCoords}
        region={currentLocation}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 3,
        }}
      >
        {markerCoords && <Marker coordinate={markerCoords} />}
      </MapView>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          gap: 6,
        }}
      >
        <Pressable
          onPress={getLocationPermission}
          android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
          style={{
            padding: 5,
            margin: 5,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
            Share Your Location{" "}
            <IonIcons name="location" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
          </Text>
        </Pressable>

        <Pressable
          onPress={navigateToMapSelect}
          android_ripple={{ color: "gray" }}
          style={{
            padding: 5,
            margin: 5,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>
            Select on Map <IonIcons name="map" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: Yup that's right
   region={mapLayout}